# CKEditor not saving in utf-8

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, ckeditor

I will try to be quick and easy to understand it. I'm having a problem with my project in PHP which I can't do anything to fix it, I have a instance of CKEditor in my website.

This is the config and the instance:

```
    <script src="assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1" id="editor" rows="10" cols="80" required value="<?php if($error) echo $profdesc; ?> ">
            <?php echo $profdesc; ?>
    </textarea>

    <script>
      CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        contentsCss: "assets/ckeditor/test.css",
        uiColor: '#428bca',
        extraPlugins: 'wordcount,lineheight,colorbutton,smiley',
                    wordcount: {
                        showWordCount: true,
                      showParagraphs: false,
                      showCharCount: true,
                        maxCharCount: 3000,
                        paragraphsCountGreaterThanMaxLengthEvent: function (currentLength, maxLength) {
                            $("#informationparagraphs").css("background-color", "crimson").css("color", "white").text(currentLength + "/" + maxLength + " - paragraphs").show();
                        },
                        wordCountGreaterThanMaxLengthEvent: function (currentLength, maxLength) {
                            $("#informationword").css("background-color", "crimson").css("color", "white").text(currentLength + "/" + maxLength + " - word").show();
                        },
                        charCountGreaterThanMaxLengthEvent: function (currentLength, maxLength) {
                            $("#informationchar").css("background-color", "crimson").css("color", "white").text(currentLength + "/" + maxLength + " - char").show();
                        },
                        charCountLessThanMaxLengthEvent: function (currentLength, maxLength) {
                            $("#informationchar").css("background-color", "white").css("color", "black").hide();
                        },
                        paragraphsCountLessThanMaxLengthEvent: function (currentLength, maxLength) {
                            $("#informationparagraphs").css("background-color", "white").css("color", "black").hide();
                        },
                        wordCountLessThanMaxLengthEvent: function (currentLength, maxLength) {
                            $("#informationword").css("background-color", "white").css("color", "black").hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
  </script>
```

Everything works fine.. until I update the "description" with this editor, I have all my tables and mysql to UTF-8, or at least I think I have it.
It could be a problem with the UPDATE SQL, here is the rest of the code.
In this case I'm trying to save "Olá" in the DB.

```
if(mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET username='" . $name1 .
       "',description='" . $descr . "',gender='" . $gender .
       "',location='" . $location . "',ocupation='" . $ocupation .
       "' WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['usr_id'] . "'"))
```

This is the result on the DB:
[image]

Comment: Make sure that the column/table is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it! All I had to do was to put a:

```
mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');
```

before the:

```
if(mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET username='" . $name1 . "',description='" . $descr . "',gender='" . $gender . "',location='" . $location . "',ocupation='" . $ocupation . "' WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['usr_id'] . "'")) {
```

And the result was: "Olá"